# Can I have multiple awk actions without inserting newlines?

Tags: bash, awk

I'm a newbie with very small and specific needs. I'm using awk to parse something and I need to generate uninterrupted lines of text assembled from several pieces in the original text. **But awk inserts a newline in the output whenever I use a semicolon**.

Simplest example of what I mean:

Original text:

```
1 2
```

awk command:

```
{ print $1; print $2 }
```

The output will be:

```
1
2
```

The thing is that I need the output to be a single line, and I also need to use the semicolons, because I have to do multiple actions on the original text, not all of them *print*.

Also, using ORS=" " causes a whole lot of different problems, so it's not an option.

Is there any other way that I can have multiple actions in the same line without newline insertion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The newlines in the output are nothing to do with you using semicolons to separate statements in your script, they are because `print` outputs the arguments you give it followed by the contents of `ORS` and the default value of `ORS` is newline.

You may want some version of either of these:

```
$ echo '1 2' | awk '{printf "%s ", $1; printf "%s ", $2; print ""}'
1 2 
$

$ echo '1 2' | awk -v ORS=' ' '{print $1; print $2; print "\n"}'
1 2
 $

$ echo '1 2' | awk -v ORS= '{print $1; print " "; print $2; print "\n"}'
1 2
$
```

but it's hard to say without knowing more about what you're trying to do.

At least scan through the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to get some understanding of the basics before trying to program in awk or you're going to waste a lot of your time and learn a lot of bad habits first.

Comment: @John1024 - the `$` was there deliberately to show the spurious space the 2nd version would add before the end of the line.

Comment: For the second example, I would suggest `echo '1 2' | awk -v ORS=' ' '{print $1; print $2; printf "\n"}'` because it eliminates the extra space.

Comment: OK.  It struck me as odd because it lacked parallelism with the other examples.

Comment: No, it just hides it at the end of the line. I want it to be visible so the OP knows what he's getting. And yes, I know it's not visible in the first one but it's still there. They're 3 different examples of output.

Comment: Rolledback.  It would be clearer if all had the following prompt, not just one.  (+1 regardless).

Comment: Fair enough, prompts added for the other 2 as well.

Comment: Thanks. My needs are extremely simple so I'll stick to the printf way. Sorry for not posing the correct question, I'm not a programmer and even navigating man pages is very difficult for me (that's why I didn't even think that the culprit was print instead of the semicolon). Also the example was simplified, I need multiple actions because some are print and other are if. Thanks again.

Comment: What's `the printf way`? If it's what I showed - you almost certainly do NOT want to do that as it'll add trailing blanks to the end of the line. If it's something else, you have to be careful as it's easy to write something that works today and fails for other input later. We can help you but only if you edit your question to show a concise, testable example of what you actually want to do. Oh, and man pages are for reference **after** you learn how to do something, they are NOT the source of information for learning how to do something.

Answer (score 0):

You have better control of the output if you use `printf`, e.g.

```
awk '{ printf "%s %s\n",$1,$2 }'
```

Comment: Hard-coding newline in `printf` is a bad idea which makes your script platform specific, Use default `ORS` instead.

Comment: @sjsam : what platform specific ? Win64 can open files with trailing `\n` instead of  `\r\n` just fine. And we can easily assume `MacOS Classic` is beyond dead at this point, so `\r`-only is moot for all intents and purposes. As for `IBM's EBCDIC`, they can either adapt to the current reality, or go the way of the dodo bird.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print $1 $2}'
```

Is the solution in this case

Comment: No, it's not. That will concatenate the fields and doesn't address the OPs question of which the 2 prints was just a sample.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

You're getting newlines because `print` sends *OFS* to standard output after each print statement. You can format the output in a variety of other ways, but the key is generally to invoke only a single `print` or `printf` statement regardless of how many fields or values you want to print.

### Use Commas

One way to do this is to use a single call to `print` using commas to separate arguments. This will insert OFS between the printed arguments. For example:

```
$ echo '1 2' | awk '{print $1, $2}'
1 2
```

### Don't Separate Arguments

If you don't want *any* separation in your output, just pass all the arguments to a single `print` statement. For example:

```
$ echo '1 2' | awk '{print $1 $2}' 
12
```

### Formatted Strings

If you want more control than that, use formatted strings using `printf`. For example:

```
$ echo '1 2' | awk '{printf "%s...%s\n", $1, $2}' 
1...2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo "1 2" | awk '{print $1 " " $2}'
1 2
```